# Who is the current owner of US 6352164 B1?

Tags: ownership, us6352164

Does anyone know who is now the owner of this Patent (US6352164 B1) at this time? 
It seems the onership of the company has changed hands.

Answer (score 1):

Google patents now pulls in the USPTO assignment database and integrates the information into its summary of a US patent or application. A screen shot:

[image]